# Network configuration DNS problem

Tags: networking

I have installed ubuntu server 14.04 behind router and when i use the server in DHCP mode work fine he now namesaver, but if i make in static IP with /etc/network/interfaces, and i reboot, i have internet second or two and then i do not have net and when i go to interfaces the static rules are ok but in namesaver DNS mode /etc/resolv.conf i do not have nothing i put namsaver like router ip xxx.xxx.xxx.1 and nameserver 8.8.8.8 again nothing do not remember or some conflict erase the settings .

PLEASE HELP

Comment: May we see your static address /etc/network/interfaces file?

Comment: auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.100.42
     network 192.168.0.0
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     broadcast 192.168.100.255
     gateway 192.168.100.1

Comment: # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

Comment: no nameserver if i put manually it will be erased, in auto eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp , work normally

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you amend your /etc/network/interfaces file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.100.42
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.100.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.100.1
```

Restart the interface:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```